# OAuth in asp.net MVC projects

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, oauth

How come online i see both of these?  Is there any difference?

```
var OAuthOptions = new OAuthAuthorizationServerOptions
{
    TokenEndpointPath = new PathString("/Token"),
    AuthorizeEndpointPath = new PathString("/Account/Authorize"),
    Provider = new SimpleAuthorizationServerProvider(UserRepository, UserStore),
    AccessTokenExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromDays(14),
    AllowInsecureHttp = true
};
app.UseOAuthBearerTokens(OAuthOptions);
```

and

```
app.UseOAuthAuthorizationServer(new OAuthAuthorizationServerOptions
{
    AllowInsecureHttp = true,

    TokenEndpointPath = new PathString("/token"),
    AccessTokenExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromHours(8),

    Provider = new SimpleAuthorizationServerProvider(UserRepository, UserStore)
});
app.UseOAuthBearerAuthentication(new OAuthBearerAuthenticationOptions());
```

How come the method UseOAuthBearerTokens takes in OAuthAuthorizationServerOptions as a parameter?

Comment: Good question. I don't know if it's just me, but I think the whole Authorization/Authentication/OAuth part of the current state of ASP.NET is an absolute mess.

Comment: Do people recommend using something else?

Answer (score 2):

I believe the first one, UseOAuthBearerTokens(options), was added in Web API 2.1, and it encapsulates the call to UseOAuthAuthorizationServer and UseOAuthBearerAuthentication.

Unfortunately, a lot of samples in articles/blogs on the web don't include a publish date, so it's hard to track whether the code is still applicable.  And given the speed at which these APIs are being updated, I don't think it will get less confusing.

Here's the code from the Owin.AppBuilderExtensions.cs found in the Microsoft.Owin.Security packages, for reference, as of Web Api v2.2:

```cs
public static void UseOAuthBearerTokens(this IAppBuilder app, OAuthAuthorizationServerOptions options)
        {
            if (app == null)
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException("app");
            }
            if (options == null)
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException("options");
            }

            app.UseOAuthAuthorizationServer(options);

            app.UseOAuthBearerAuthentication(new OAuthBearerAuthenticationOptions
            {
                AccessTokenFormat = options.AccessTokenFormat,
                AccessTokenProvider = options.AccessTokenProvider,
                AuthenticationMode = options.AuthenticationMode,
                AuthenticationType = options.AuthenticationType,
                Description = options.Description,
                Provider = new ApplicationOAuthBearerProvider(),
                SystemClock = options.SystemClock
            });

            app.UseOAuthBearerAuthentication(new OAuthBearerAuthenticationOptions
            {
                AccessTokenFormat = options.AccessTokenFormat,
                AccessTokenProvider = options.AccessTokenProvider,
                AuthenticationMode = AuthenticationMode.Passive,
                AuthenticationType = DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ExternalBearer,
                Description = options.Description,
                Provider = new ExternalOAuthBearerProvider(),
                SystemClock = options.SystemClock
            });
        }
```